# gridview questions

Tags: java, android

I have a gridview layout.  I also have some images that i will be putting in the gridview as imageviews.  I want to pick and choose which images will go in what row.  That is I may have 5 images go to row 1 and 5 images may go to the row at end of the screen while all the rows in between are blank.  Unfortunately right now it only inserts pictures row by row, and you can't pick and choose what row you want to add it to. Is what I'm trying to do feasible in gridview?

Answer (score 0):

It can get little complicated using the gridview for your purpose you should use the dynamic view create a xml view for the row inflate it and add it dynamically to your parent layout.

[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588912/how-to-inflate-extended-linearlayout-from-xml)

add it to your mainlayout.