# Is there a way to define where content between the tags of a custom element goes in Android xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Say I want a reusable border layout for Android.

```
border.xml

<LinearLayout ...>
    <LinearLayout...>
        This is where I want content to go
    </LinearLayout...>
    <FrameLayout .../>
</LinearLayout ...>
```

and Border.java inflates border.xml.
Now in another view, I want to draw things inside my border. Something like

```
homepage.xml

<Border ... >
    <TextView .../>
    <TextView .../>
</Border>
```

Is there a way to tell xml where to put the content of custom tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could inflate a given ressource to your custom Border layout.

Use this inside your constructor

```
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.homepage, YOUR_SECOND_LINEARLAYOUT);
```

Comment: I'd actually like to reuse border.xml for multiple pages. So to clarify, say I have a HomepageFragment.java. In its onCreateView, would I inflate border.xml, then findViewById to get its second linear layout, then use your line?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making a class that extends say linearlayout. Inside that class you can inflate the border.xml

```
public class BorderView extends LinearLayout {
    public BorderView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       View.inflate(context, R.layout.border, this);
    }
```

Here is where I got this for an exampler:

[How to Inflate Extended LinearLayout from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588912/how-to-inflate-extended-linearlayout-from-xml)